# How much info share bitcoin nodes between other nodes?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, network, full-node, nodes

1.If we assume bitcoin nodes share the other nodes addresses in the end every node know other nodes adresses right?

---

2.If we share data through network every node share the same information other nodes so if we have 100 member in network same message will arrive to me hundred times isn't it wastefull for network?

Answer (score 2):

The IP-addesses of Bitcoin nodes are not a secret. See [addr](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#addr)

Nodes don't explicitly tell other nodes their Bitcoin addresses. Since nodes pass on details of other nodes transactions, working out which nodes originated a transaction isn't straightforward.

Since the set of Bitcoin nodes is constantly changing, and nodes go offline temporarily (or permanently), no node ever absolutely and definitely knows the IP-addresses of all nodes existing

Nodes don't communicate with *all* other nodes. Only with a few at any time.